Variable interpolation in env_file using Podman compose
I'm starting the containers using podman compose. The compose.yaml like this,
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

and varialbes are defined in .env.local like this,
# use by Drizzle ORM
DATABASE_USERNAME=dummy
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_NAME=demo

# use to start MySQL container
MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
MYSQL_USER=dummy
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret

the above configuration are working fine.
Now that there are duplicated variables like DATABASE_USERNAME and MYSQL_DATABASE and I tried to simplify the .env.local like this,
DATABASE_USERNAME=dummy
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_NAME=demo

MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret

and it looks like the interpolation does not work. Do you know what am I missing here?
See also Interpolation in Compose file specification

I think what you are trying is not possible.
Instead I suggest not seeing the .env file from a docker point of view.
Try to see it as a user that doesn't (want to) know anything about docker and only configures the services using the .env file.
Then you would have something like
DATABASE_USERNAME=dummy
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_NAME=demo
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DATABASE_USERNAME}"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

The advantage is that changes in the .env file are not so dangerous since you have no duplications.
